# Laravel 10 get Google Analytics report of users

Tags: google-analytics, laravel-10

Im trying to get the google analytics report of my users who have with their consent signin to my website with the google signin option what steps should i take to solve this when the user sigin with google it return me the id and the access token of the user i have saved that in my database and i have explored the spatie library of laravel it do provides the the function to get the google analytics but it asks for the property id and some other attributes as well so how can i get these attribute from the user.

I have completed the sigin with google functionality.